# How do I use ggplot and facet_wrap for plotting factor attributes in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, r-factor

I have a dataset with a number of attributes that share common values (a price range, e.g. "£11-£20", "£21-£30"...) stored as factors. I am trying to plot a selection of these attributes using facet_wrap and having bar plots of the count for each with the price range on the x axis.

I can obtain the graphs I'd like individually, but I'd like to group these attributes as they are related. Example code is below:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  breakfast = factor(c("£11-£20","£11-£20","£21-30","£0-£10","£11-£20")),
  lunch = factor(c("£0-£10","£11-£20","£21-30","£11-£20","£21-30")),
  dinner = factor(c("£0-£10","£31-£40","£21-30","£11-£20","£21-30")),
  voucher_used = c(0,1,1,0,1)
)
View(dat)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = breakfast, fill = factor(voucher_used))) +
  geom_bar() +
  xlab("Breakfast") +
  ylab("No.") +
  labs(fill = "Voucher Used") # +
# facet_wrap(~ lunch)
```

Ideally I'd like to add the same plots for lunch and dinner alongside - is it possible or is there another better way to achieve the same result?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible reshaping your data to long format using some `tidyverse` functions:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Data
dat <- data.frame(
  breakfast = factor(c("£11-£20","£11-£20","£21-30","£0-£10","£11-£20")),
  lunch = factor(c("£0-£10","£11-£20","£21-30","£11-£20","£21-30")),
  dinner = factor(c("£0-£10","£31-£40","£21-30","£11-£20","£21-30")),
  voucher_used = c(0,1,1,0,1)
)
#Plot
dat %>% pivot_longer(-voucher_used) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = factor(voucher_used))) +
  geom_bar() +
  xlab("Breakfast") +
  ylab("No.") +
  labs(fill = "Voucher Used") +
  facet_wrap(~ name,scales = 'free')+xlab('Var')
```

Output:

[image]